# How to generate mousewheel event in jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, mousewheel

I have web-page with two buttons, and when clicking on them I want to call mouse wheel up/down events. Not `scrollTo` or `scrollBy` - I need mousewheel.
How can I do this? Is it possible with `jquery.mousewheel` plugin or with usual Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The mouse wheel event is called 'onwheel' in modern browsers. Try triggering that one.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked well for me

```
  //Firefox
 $('#elem').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
     if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
         //scroll down
         console.log('Down');
     }else {
         //scroll up
         console.log('Up');
     }

     //prevent page fom scrolling
     return false;
 });

 //IE, Opera, Safari
 $('#elem').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
     if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
         //scroll down
         console.log('Down');
     }else {
         //scroll up
         console.log('Up');
     }

     //prevent page fom scrolling
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/bind/ *"As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document."*

Comment: I'm talking not about binding an event. I want to make browser think that mousewheel happened when user clicked a button on page.

Comment: Then on clicking the button trigge the mouse scroll with following code

 var e = jQuery.Event( "DOMMouseScroll",{delta: -650} );
                        
jQuery( "#selector" ).trigger( e );

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger the mouse wheel.
(no matter jQuery or php or something else web code can't do this)

If you want to trigger an event bind to mouse wheel.

Maybe you can try bind the same event to the button with scrollTo?

That's the same with mouse wheel.

Comment: I need to zoom, not scroll.